# Android : Auto aujust linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add dynamic multiple views horizontally in a `LinearLayout`. The problem i am facing is "all views are not displayed". Only few views are displayed and other are not displayed. All views should be auto adjusted in the `LinearLayout`.
I tried with `FrameLayout` also. But no success.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Can you please upload your code. No body on stackoverflow is sherlock holmes

Comment: Better use relative layout

Comment: Give all items weight, so all items get displayed else use relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear layout like

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layLanguage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Select Language "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spnLang"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:entries="@array/selectLang"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

use layout_weight for auto adjusted for layout as per your mobile screen size